# Get connection string of non server machine( SQL) using c#

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, connection-string, sqlconnection

I am working on windows forms application using c#.net. i have developed an application that uses sql database as backend. Using local server i am working.Now I need work on client machine who have server on the network(non server machine).How can i work with non server machine).

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your connection string. Instead of localhost or "." or your machine name, use the server machine name and sqlinstance name. More about connection strings, check http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: Thanks your reply..i dont know server machine name and sqlinstance name.can i use Remove Integrated Security=True

Answer (score 0):

Suppose when you execute your application, its address comes as

```
    http://localhost/pagename.aspx/formname
```

So instead of this, you can access it by replacing localhost by ip address of the machine

```
http://10.123.4.56/pagename.aspx/formname
```

Comment: I am using windows application.

Comment: This is local server connection string :                                        string connection = "data source=localhost;initial catalog=TWO;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;packet size=4096";